# How to show everything in the collection with Blaze Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

Hi guys so I've got a collection which has documents like this

```
{
    "_id" : "THaD5FbLjghToRHC7",
    "ipAdr" : "127.0.0.1",
    "connections" : [
        {
            "connID" : "Sohg3KRSnC2JJJfY8",
            "ipAdr" : "127.0.0.1",
            "httpHeads" : {
                "host" : "localhost:3000",
                "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36",
                "realIP" : null
            },
            "connectedAt" : ISODate("2016-08-17T13:25:56.882Z"),
            "disconnectedAt" : ISODate("2016-08-17T13:26:00.007Z")
        },
        {
            "connID" : "5N6WEgCpe4Qc3cmRD",
            "ipAdr" : "127.0.0.1",
            "httpHeads" : {
                "host" : "localhost:3000",
                "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36",
                "realIP" : null
            },
            "connectedAt" : ISODate("2016-08-18T06:08:33.213Z"),
            "disconnectedAt" : ISODate("2016-08-18T06:11:44.102Z")
        },
        {
            "connID" : "Hxggbanp3bo5nh9mi",
            "ipAdr" : "127.0.0.1",
            "httpHeads" : {
                "host" : "localhost:3000",
                "userAgent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36",
                "realIP" : null
            },
            "connectedAt" : ISODate("2016-08-18T06:25:16.863Z"),
            "disconnectedAt" : null
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-08-17T13:25:56.882Z")
}
```

This is the result when I type in my terminal

```
db.ips.find({}).pretty()
```

Now I want this same result to have on my page rendered by Blaze, but I cannot think of a way to do that. How can I display big collections and documents in a readable and organized format using Blaze?

Comment: You can use publish and subscribe to achieve this.

Comment: I'm very new to this, would you provide some example, please?

Comment: Here you go : https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe

Comment: Are you asking about how to display nested properties and elements in the connections array (along with their nested properties)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to stringify the data using `JSON.stringify`

Then, you can print it inside of a set of `<pre> </pre>` tags

Example: [http://jsfiddle.net/K83cK/](http://jsfiddle.net/sb2xhxyf/)

Comment: This way I get a string but not the exact string I need, I do this 
`return JSON.stringify(Ips.find({},{sort: { createdAt: -1 } }),undefined,2);`
and get this
`{
  "collection": {
    "name": "ips",
    "_docs": {
      "_map": {}
    },
    "_observeQueue": {
      "_tasks": [],
      "_running": false,
      "_runTimeout": null
...
   `
and so on. I need to get my documents with all their fields.

Comment: oh I just tried doing it like this `  return JSON.stringify(Ips.find({},{sort: { createdAt: -1 } }).fetch(),undefined,2);` and it works great!